# VBA: For Loop hitting Automation Error -2147221080

Tags: excel, vba, automation

Here is my code.

My purpose is, open a test excel and then save as a filename contained within the 'Test' sheet.  I simply want to automate the task of saving an Excel for each of a list of filenames.

```
Sub POPButton1_Click()           
    
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Test.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim filename As String
    filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Test.xlsx"
    
    Dim sjk As Workbook
    Set sjk = Workbooks.Open(filename)
    Dim saveName As String
                    
    For i = 1 To LastRow
            
        saveName = Test.Cells(i, "D").Value
                
        sjk.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & saveName

        sjk.Close
        
        
    Next i
        
End Sub
```

The first excel is saved just fine, then I hit the bug. -2147221080 Automation error.

The line of code that highlights on debug is:

```
sjk.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & saveName
```

I have looked around on this site and many others, as it appears a common bug, and I get the feeling it is an easy fix, but nothing I have tried has worked.  I have re-written the code many times to get it to this point - I just can't see where the error is...

Comment: What is the variable `Test` and where is it defined?

Comment: Test is the name of a worksheet, it doesn't need to be defined when you use the base name for the sheet, as Excel recognises it as a sheet in the workbook. You could read it as Sheet1 if you preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah!  I think the answer is that you close the file but then never re-open it.

Move your Set sjk = Workbooks.Open(filename) inside your For loop at the top.

That should fix it for you.

Comment: Ok added a 5 second delay, did not stop the debug error.  Grr to pressing enter thinking you will get a new line....I can see the loop waiting, for the 5 secs, the excel is created and closes, but still the same automation error.

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect the real solution.  I just tested this and found the problem is in closing the file in the loop but never opening it again.

Comment: I knew it was going to be simple....though I also think the delay is a useful thing to have in the loop, as I think it would have broken eventually....thanks!